# SVNException: svn: {file} not under version control

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I am storing a folder under version control. This folder is a virtual folder and is displayed as a single file. When I compare flow1.iwp as 'Latest from Repository' I get the following error:

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: '/home/akravets/dev/workspaces/runtime-trunk/test1/Flows/flow1.iwp/.compiledFlow' is not under version control
>   at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.diff(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2462)
>   at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.ShowDifferencesAsUnifiedDiffOperationWC.execute(ShowDifferencesAsUnifiedDiffOperationWC.java:50)
>   at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.SVNOperation.run(SVNOperation.java:90)
>   at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ProgressDialogRunnableContext$3.run(ProgressDialogRunnableContext.java:100)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
>   at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ProgressDialogRunnableContext$2.run(ProgressDialogRunnableContext.java:97)
>   at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: '/home/akravets/dev/workspaces/runtime-trunk/test1/Flows/flow1.iwp/.compiledFlow' is not under version control
>   at org.tigris.subversion.javahl.JavaHLObjectFactory.throwException(JavaHLObjectFactory.java:778)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.throwException(SVNClientImpl.java:1850)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.diff(SVNClientImpl.java:2035)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.diff(SVNClientImpl.java:1990)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.diff(SVNClientImpl.java:1985)
>   at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.diff(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2459)
>   ... 6 more
>   Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: '/home/akravets/dev/workspaces/runtime-trunk/test1/Flows/flow1.iwp/.compiledFlow' is not under version control
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.getVersionedEntry(SVNWCAccess.java:621)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:499)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:465)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNDiffClient.doDiffURLWC(SVNDiffClient.java:2725)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNDiffClient.doDiff(SVNDiffClient.java:685)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.diff(SVNClientImpl.java:2024)
>   ... 9 more

Is there way I can bypass comparison of files that are not under version control? In this case even considering them for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add flag to add unversioned files during compare:

```
SVNDiffClient diffClient = SVNClientManager.newInstance().getDiffClient(); 
diffClient.getDiffGenerator().setDiffUnversioned(true);
```